# Como puedo obtener el numero mas repetido en un arreglo y mostrarlo en consola

Tags: javascript

Tengo este arreglo para obtener el numero que mas se repite e imprimirlo las veces que se repitió

```
var myArray = [1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8];
```

La respuesta necesito que salga asi

```
Repetido: 3
Numero: 8
```

Probe este codigo y no me resulto como esperaba

```
 var myArray = [1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8];
 let duplicados = [];

 const tempArray = [...myArray].sort();

 for (let i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
   if (tempArray[i + 1] === tempArray[i]) {
     duplicados.push(tempArray[i]);
   }
 }

 console.log(duplicados);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar un objeto para contar las ocurrencias de cada número y luego usar un bucle para encontrar el máximo

```js
let myArray = [1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8];
let contador = {}; // objeto para guardar las ocurrencias
let maximo = 0; // variable para guardar el máximo
let numeroMasRepetido; // variable para guardar el número más repetido

// recorremos el arreglo y contamos las ocurrencias de cada número
myArray.forEach(function(numero) {
  contador[numero] = (contador[numero] || 0) + 1;
});

// recorremos el objeto y buscamos el máximo
for (var numero in contador) {
  if (contador[numero] > maximo) {
    maximo = contador[numero];
    numeroMasRepetido = numero;
  }
}

// mostramos el resultado en consola
console.log("El número más repetido es " + numeroMasRepetido + " y se repite " + maximo + " veces.");
```

Comment: dale bro gracias por el código me funciono

Answer (score 3):

Una versión más simplificada:

- Iteras tu arreglo.
- Cuentas la cantidad de veces que se repiten cada elemento de tu arreglo.
- La cantidad de veces que se repiten, lo almacenas en un objeto.
- Ingresas a los valores del objeto y obtienes el mayor repetido con `reduce()`.

Ejemplo (explicación en comentarios):

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8];
let contador = {}; // Creo un objeto para almacenar la cantidad de veces que se repite cada elemento del array.

myArray.forEach(function (x) {
  // En cada iteración, cuento la cantidad de veces que se repite cada elemento actual del arreglo, y lo almaceno en "contador"
  contador[x] = (contador[x] || 0) + 1;
});

// Hasta aquí ya sabemos la cantidad de veces que se repite cada elemento del arreglo. Entonces,
// ingresemos a los valores de las claves de "contador" y usamos reduce() para encontrar el número
// que se repite más veces.
let masRepetido = Object.keys(contador).reduce(function (a, b) {
  return contador[a] > contador[b] ? a : b; // aquí retorna el número con mayor cantidad de repeticiones.
});

console.log('Repetido:', contador[masRepetido]); // obtenemos la cantidad de veces que se repitió el número.
console.log('Numero:', masRepetido); // obtenemos el número que más se repitió.
```

Answer (score 2):

Este método utiliza dos **reduce**:

- El primero solo acumula
- El segundo agrega el número más repetido

```js
  const myArray = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8];

  const max = Object.entries(
    myArray.reduce(
      (a, n) => ({
        ...a,
        [n]: (a[n] || 0) + 1
      }),
      {}
    )
  ).reduce((a, n) => (a[1] > n[1] ? a : n));

  console.log(`numero es: ${max[0]} se repite: ${max[1]}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Implementado usando reduce** (*Le permite no solo acceder al valor más repetido, también al conteo de todos los valores del array*)

Teniendo en cuenta el obtener dos valores, estos se inician en el mismo método tipo: objeto.

Para `maxNum`: acc y `maxCount`: val (--Guía--). Luego solo es actualizar `acc` según las condiciones, verificando si el valor actual(val) existe en el acumulador(acc), es decir: Si existe aumenta en 1 de lo contrario se agrega en acc con valor de 1.

Luego se verifica si el valor actual de *acc* es mayor que *maxCount*. Si lo es, se actualizan *maxCount* y *maxNum* del objeto acumulador con el valor actual.

```
     const myArray = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8];
     const count = myArray.reduce(
        (acc, val) => (
          (acc[val] = (acc[val] || 0) + 1) > acc.maxCount &&
            (acc.maxCount = acc[val]) &&
            (acc.maxNum = val),
          acc
        ),
        { maxNum: null, maxCount: 0 }
      )
      //Valor más repetido
      console.log(`El número más repetido es: ${count.maxNum} con: ${count.maxCount} repeticiones`)
  //Conteo en general
  console.log(count)
```